# Problem in importing tensorflow_data_validation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-data-validation

I tried to import and use the `tensorflow_data_validation` library, but I faced this error:

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 1.25.1 (c:\users\amoosi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core[grpc]!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5'), {'google-cloud-bigquery-storage'})
```

I'm using `Python 3.9.12`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the package `google-api-core` has a version conflict with the package `google-cloud-bigquery-storage`.

The current installed version of `google-api-core` is 1.25.1, and the error is giving you a list of the accepted versions, which are above the one that you have.

To update type this in a terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-core
```